# Basic Javascript - mouse click to change picture and caption

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid, addeventlistener

## Objective

Two categories (i.e. dog and cat) of images, image and image caption. I want to click on that image and have it change to a picture of the second category, if you click again it changes to the other category. So somehow i need to define the images within one of two categories then alternate them on click.

---

### HTML

```
<img src="img/dogImg.jpg" alt="" id="imgClickAndChange">
<h1 id="title">Dog Title</h1>
<p id="caption">caption for dog.</p>
```

### Javascript

```
function changeImage() {

    if (document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src = "img/dogImg.jpg") 
    {
        document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src = "img/catImg.jpg";
        document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = "Cat Title";
        document.getElementById("caption").innerHTML = "caption for cat.";

    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src = "img/dogImg.jpg";
        document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = "Dog Title";
        document.getElementById("caption").innerHTML = "caption for dog.";
    }
}

var el = document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange");
el.addEventListener("click", changeImage, false);
```

Right now it seems to be changing to the cat info okay, but I can't figure out how to make it go back to dog. Having the caption for the dog in both the HTML and Javascript seem redundant. Is there a simpler way to do this whole thing? Thanks!

Comment: `console.log(document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src)`; Is it what you expect it to be?

Comment: You comparision rule is incorrect, you need doble equals: `if (document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src == "img/dogImg.jpg") `

Comment: You're assigning the src in the if statements, not comparing them.. Use double equals?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got an tiny mistake in your code.

Instead of

```
if (document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src = "img/dogImg.jpg")
```

do

```
if (document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src === "img/dogImg.jpg")
```

Comment: Despite whether I change that if statement to have == or ===, when I click, nothing (not the picture or caption) changes. Do I need an else if statement?

Comment: try `if(document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src.slice(-10) === "dogImg.jpg")` or use `if(document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").getAttribute("src") === "img/dogImg.jpg")` like @Zub said

Answer (score 0):

With `.src` you get absolute path to the image. Use `getAttribute` instead

Try this code:

```
if (document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").getAttribute("src") === "img/dogImg.jpg") {
    document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").setAttribute("src", "img/dogImg.jpg")
    ...
```